# In R, how to multiply multiple rows for each unique entry in a different variable

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a data frame in R with student grade data. Here's a sample:

```
df <- data.frame(
  "courseno" = c(101, 101, 101, 236, 236, 236, 101, 101, 101),
  "termID" = c("T", "E", "S", "T", "E", "S", "T", "E", "S"),
  "studentID" = c(9100, 9100, 9100, 8640, 8640, 8640, 3461, 3461, 3461),
  "grade" = c(92, 79, 91, 83, 87, 84, 78, 92, 83))

##        courseno termID studentID grade
## 1           101     T       9100    92
## 2           101     E       9100    79
## 3           101     S       9100    90

## 4           236     T       8640    83
## 5           236     E       8640    87
## 6           236     S       8640    84

## 7           101     T       3461    78
## 8           101     E       3461    92
## 9           101     S       3461    83
```

For each course, a student earns 3 grades: T (the grade on everything prior to the final exam), E (the grade on the final exam), and S (the ultimate grade in the course). The relationship is S = 0.8T + 0.2E. However, some teachers "bump up" a student's final S grade if the student is, e.g., on the border between an A and B.

For each unique combination of courseno and studentID, I'm trying to calculate the theoretical value of S and compare it to the actual value of S that the teacher awarded. I'm storing the results of these calculations (along with the corresponding courseno & studentID) in a new data frame with 1 line per unique courseno+studentID combination.

I've achieved the desired output, but it's **really** slow. I feel like there should be a quicker way using dplyr. Here's my current method:

```
library(dplyr)

# create a code to use for looking up each unique combination of student & course
df <- df %>% mutate(course.student = paste0(courseno, studentID))

# generate master lists that will be populated by the for loop and used to build the new df
courseno.all <- NULL
studentID.all <- NULL
t.awarded.all <- NULL
e.awarded.all <- NULL
s.awarded.all <- NULL
s.calculated.all <- NULL
difference.all <- NULL

for(i in unique(df$course.student)){
  # store info for the ith record in a list so it can be added to the new df
  courseno.i <- df[df$course.student==i & df$termID == "S","courseno"]
  studentID.i <- df[df$course.student==i & df$termID == "S","studentID"]
  t.awarded.i <- df[df$course.student==i & df$termID == "T","grade"]
  e.awarded.i <- df[df$course.student==i & df$termID == "E","grade"]
  s.awarded.i <- df[df$course.student==i & df$termID == "S","grade"]

  # calculate a value of S using the equation S = 0.8T + 0.2E
  s.calculated.i <- round((t.awarded.i*0.8 + e.awarded.i*0.2),0)

  # calculate the amount of "grade bump" the teacher gave
  difference.i <- s.awarded.i - s.calculated.i

  # combine the ith values into master lists with all other i records
  courseno.all <- c(courseno.all, courseno.i)
  studentID.all <- c(studentID.all, studentID.i)
  t.awarded.all <- c(t.awarded.all, t.awarded.i)
  e.awarded.all <- c(e.awarded.all, e.awarded.i)
  s.awarded.all <- c(s.awarded.all, s.awarded.i)
  s.calculated.all <- c(s.calculated.all, s.calculated.i)
  difference.all <- c(difference.all, difference.i)
}

# use the master lists to build a new data frame

df.new <- data.frame(courseno = courseno.all, 
                     studentID = studentID.all, 
                     t.awarded = t.awarded.all, 
                     e.awarded = e.awarded.all, 
                     s.awarded = s.awarded.all, 
                     s.calculated = s.calculated.all,
                     difference = difference.all)
```

This gives the desired output, which is:

```
##     courseno   studentID   t.awarded   e.awarded   s.awarded   s.calculated   difference
## 1   101        9100         92         80          91          90             1
## 2   236        8640         83         87          84          84             0
## 3   101        3461         78         92          83          81             2
```

But my actual data frame is over 100,000 rows and a few dozen columns. Is there a quicker way to achieve this using dplyr and mutate()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `dcast` from `data.table` and it should be efficient for bigger dataset

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df), courseno + studentID ~ termID, value.var = 'grade')[,
 S_calculated := 0.8 * T + 0.2 * E][, difference := S - S_calculated][]
#    courseno studentID  E  S  T S_calculated difference
#1:      101      3461 92 83 78         80.8        2.2
#2:      101      9100 79 91 92         89.4        1.6
#3:      236      8640 87 84 83         83.8        0.2
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing your expertise!! That is **incredibly** fast.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you're after:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = termID, values_from = grade) %>%
  mutate(
    S_calculated = 0.8 * T + 0.2 * E,
    difference = S - S_calculated
  )
# # A tibble: 3 x 7
#   courseno studentID     T     E     S S_calculated difference
#      <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>        <dbl>      <dbl>
# 1      101      9100    92    79    91         89.4      1.60 
# 2      236      8640    83    87    84         83.8      0.200
# 3      101      3461    78    92    83         80.8      2.20
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer in terms of dplyr! This is exactly what I asked for and works perfectly. I'd select this as the correct answer except that the other method is quicker (which is my fault for not specifying in the question that speed was the top priority). I learned a lot from this answer too.